# RVIZ: Should fixed frame be disappearing in tf display?

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a recent update of hydro the fixed frame in the tf in rviz is disappearing after the timeout time. Is this the intended behavior or is it a bug that should be reported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167576/rviz:-should-fixed-frame-be-disappearing-in-tf-display?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2014-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've observed this as well, I think it's normal. It definitely makes the display less cluttered.

As long as you're not seeing errors on other frames, I wouldn't worry about it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2014-05-21**:
Well, it was a change in behavior that made me spend half an hour so debugging my code and looking for why the transform was not sent correctly.... But we find the world frame very useful in our application with one or more quadrotors since we use the world frame to check the display orientation.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-21**:
You can display the world frame by explicitly adding an "Axes" display type and specifying the world frame.